# What to do about question which are inappropriately migrated from MSE to MO?

Tags: discussion, math-stackexchange

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178022/average-deviation-of-group-sizes) has been migrated from MSE by a moderator as well as closed for being off-topic. As I recall, MSE consider to have in principle a scope that encompasses the scope of MO (i.e. all math questions), so that in principle no question would *have* to be migrated this way. There certainly are questions which *should* be migrated to MO since they would fit best here, but in this case it feels not very appropriate. Should we migrate it back -but it would feel a bit rude? Is there a way to discuss between the two sides what to do with such a question? Do I just fail to see why this question is suitable for MO?

Comment: I have migrated it back, and I don't think it is rude to do so. The question doesn't seem to be appropriate for MO.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of the question, and I would not deem it rude to migrate it back to MSE. Actually, I was considering a way to put it back, but since I could not publish it again on MO, I felt blocked. So I'm going to flag it to migrate it back to MSE.

Answer (score 4):

Just close the question as off-topic, this will reverse the migration. The original will stay closed, but you can flag it for moderator attention on MSE to get it reopened.

Closing is the main method to reject migrations as intended by Stack Exchange, using it will cause the least amount of trouble.

Remigration is possible, but to be honest this is a really, really scary option. I'm a moderator on two other SE sites, and I have no idea what would happen if I tried to remigrate a question. I know from previous cases that all kinds of stuff can go wrong in multiple migration cases, the software is simply not designed for this case.

Comment: Now MSE has two versions of the post. It's an interesting way to duplicate things. Now MSE moderators can migrate the two copies back to MO, and those will be migrated back and so on. In 32 cycles we'll probably have crashed at least some piece of software in the servers! :-) And if this question gets upvoted anywhere along the way, this vote will replicate and duplicate!

Comment: Here's what happened. OP asked the moderators at MSE to migrate to MO. They did. Then a question is raised whether it's indeed appropriate for MO, and OP came to conclusion that it wasn't after all, so asked to have it migrated back. So that's what I did. I see now that it would have been better just to have closed it, and that's what I'll do next time, but somehow I don't think the network is going to come crashing down as a result. If one is closed as a duplicate, then we're back to square one.

Comment: I have migrated migrated questions in the past (it has been some time). IIRC, you first need to break the link between the first copy and the second copy by erasing the migration history, then the post becomes a normal one and can be migrated.

Comment: @Todd: ah, now I feel guilty. I was the original mod who migrated it over to MO. Sorry.

Comment: @mixedmath As you can probably tell, I also feel a little guilty for how all this panned out (sorry right back atcha). Anyway, no worries; I guess the duplicate was eliminated and all is well.